# Deleting every 3rd and 5th line, but not the 15th in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to look for a way to delete every 3rd and 5th line but not the 15th using sed, but this is the thing: you can't make use of the ~ way (GNU). It has to be something like

```
sed 'n;n;d' test
```

but I can't figure out how to combine the 3...

Example input

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Example output:

```
1
2
4
7
8
11
13
14
15
```

It'll need to be in sed, no awk or perl

Comment: `sed` is definitely not the best tool for this.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugh:

```
$ seq 15 | sed -n 'p;n;p;n;n;p;n;n;n;p;n;p;n;n;n;p;n;n;p;n;p;n;p'
1
2
4
7
8
11
13
14
15
```

Answer (score 3):

awk command is easier to understand for this requirement:

```
awk 'NR==15 || (NR%3 && NR%5)' file
1
2
4
7
8
11
13
14
15
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0~15b;0~3d;0~5d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu sed:

```
sed '15p;0~3d;0~5d' test
```

here is the test result from above awk/sed commands:

```
seq 99 |awk 'NR==15 || (NR%3 && NR%5)' > anubhava.txt
seq 99 |sed -n 'p;n;p;n;n;p;n;n;n;p;n;p;n;n;n;p;n;n;p;n;p;n;p' > glenn.jackman.txt
seq 99 |sed '0~15b;0~3d;0~5d'  > potong.txt
seq 99 |sed '15p;0~3d;0~5d' > bmw.txt

$diff anubhava.txt glenn.jackman.txt
17a18
> 30
25a27
> 45
33a36
> 60
41a45
> 75
49a54
> 90
$ diff -q anubhava.txt potong.txt
Files anubhava.txt and potong.txt differ   # same problem that can't delete line 30, 45, 60, etc.
$ diff -q anubhava.txt bmw.txt
$
```